# Clarification needed in Definability versus Leibnizian structure chapter on Hamkins's book

Tags: first-order-logic, model-theory, philosophy

In Lectures on the Philosophy of Mathematics, chapter 1, 1.10 Structuralism, there is the sentence:

> For example, the real ordered field $<\mathbb{R},+,·,<,0,1>$ is
> Leibnizian, since for any two distinct real numbers...

The question I have is what it really means "the real ordered field $<\mathbb{R},+,·,<,0,1>$" in this context?

Or in other words, which tools I have at my disposal to "prove" it is Leibnizian?

I guess at minimum it means there is a first order language with equality and logical symbols, and signature $"<+,·,<,0,1"$, with enough variable symbols that allows me to write first order formulas.

I suppose I have intrinsically the first order non-logical axioms that "defines" the concepts of ordered field, and in consequence, I have the first order deductive aparatus to use the non-logical axioms to prove things in the object theory.

But I think I have more than that, isn't it? The original statement "the real ordered field..." implies that I have a concrete model in some background theory, isn't it?

Like I have a concrete structure defined maybe using ZFC or Second Order Arithmetic that somehow defines what this structure is in its own terms (in the background theory terms).

It doesn't really matter which background theory we are using to define "the real ordered field" just because it is categorical?

An last, loosely speaking, it seems as if the first order object theory is the weakest model, in the sense it can only prove whatever it is true in any model. In the other side a concrete model in the background theory, in general can "prove" things that the object theory can't. If for example another model can "prove" the negation of this thing in its background theory, then the thing becomes undecidable in the first order theory.

Comment: I guess the tools you have at your disposal are those of the first-order theory of the real ordered field, i.e. $Th(\mathbb{R},\times,\cdot,<,0,1)$.

Comment: But then, I guess it is not posible to prove with a first order theory that the structure is Leibnizian. If we were able to do it, by Lowenheim-Skolem theorem, model of any infinite cardinalities would be Leibnizian, isn't it?

Comment: The tools you have at your disposal is all of maths! "$\Bbb R$ is Leibnizian" is a meta-statement about one fixed model of the theory of ordered fields. You do not need to prove it inside a formal theory (unless you take the view that maths always happens in a base theory like ZFC). Indeed you will find it quite hard to state that as a first-order sentence in the language of ordered fields!

Comment: Is a philosofical position to require that maths happen in a base theory? Without a base theory how can you proof "$\Bbb R$ is Leibnizian"? Just looking at the structure in the platonic realm?

Comment: What a structuralist would say? Look I have a fixed model of the theory of ordered fields. I proved that any other model would be isomorphic to this fixed model. So the theory of ordered fields is categorical, so it is something. And this something is Leibnizian. But this something is not really "a particular fixed model of the theory of ordered fields". To use a particular fixed model of the theory of ordered fields is just for making happy some formalist out there. Is that a position?

Comment: I'm glad you're happier about it now! I'd like to point out it's not true that the theory of ordered fields is categorical, nor is it $\kappa$-categorical for any $\kappa$, as there are non-elementarily equivalent models of it, so I don't think a structuralist would say that. What we're showing is Leibnizian is specifically $\Bbb R$, which is an object in its own right, characterised by the second-order meta-fact it's order-complete. You can't do this using the first-order theory $\mathrm{Th}(\Bbb R)$ as by Lowenheim-Skolem, this theory has models of cardinality too large to be Leibnizian.

Comment: I see. Instead of theory of ordered fields I should say theory of complete ordered fields. :)

Answer (score 1):

The next quote from Wikipedia explain my issue:

> Structures are sometimes referred to as "first-order structures". This
> is misleading, as nothing in their definition ties them to any
> specific logic, and in fact they are suitable as semantic objects both
> for very restricted fragments of first-order logic such as that used
> in universal algebra, and for second-order logic.

In short, every time I read structure I automatically assumed it was a "first-order structure".

Nevermind, with Izaak comment and this, now it is easier to follow the arguments... :)